# Rendering user uploaded html5/js games inside a django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-media

I am sure there is a very simple way to solve my problem but I am not experienced enough to think of anything useful. I have a website on which I want to be able to add html5/js games I make on. It will be a very simple site; a template that acts as a directory with all the games in it and a template in which I render the selected game. So far it's simple.

When I finish a game I want to upload it to the website. I do it by uploading a zip of the game with the admin page. The zip is unzipped and stored inside the media folder. Something like: "media/id_of_game/game_folder"

A typical game is comprised of an html page, several javascript files and a few images.

This is where I have the problem. How do I render this game inside of my django template?  I have tried but the relative paths inherent to the game itself are broken.

My template url is as follows: example

- mysite.com/demo/game-1/

And the images/javascript/.. I need for my game are in example

- mysite.com/media/id_of_game/game_folder/main.js
- mysite.com/media/id_of_game/game_folder/index.html
- mysite.com/media/id_of_game/game_folder/templates/random_image.png
- mysite.com/media/id_of_game/game_folder/js/awesome_game_library.js

The relative paths are completely broken.

Thanks a lot to all the django masters who read up to here! Hopefully you will be able to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem.

I have added this to the urls.py:

```
url(r'^demo/game/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<path>.+)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/media/demo/elements/%(id)s/%(path)s')),
```

This means that when I access this:

- mysite.com/demo/game/1/my_awesome_picture.jpg

I get:

- mysite.com/media/demo/elements/1/my_awesome_picture.jpg

Is it ok to redirect files with django's urls.py like this or should I change the settings of nginx to achieve the same thing?